# Delphi - procedure return a error

Tags: delphi

I'm having problems in my code but can not find the solution, already modified in various ways but no success.

Code:

```
private
{ Private declarations }
procedure getImgInfo(Sender: TObject; A, B: String);
```

And:

```
procedure TfMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
i, Idx, Left, Top, Count : integer;
Graph : TGraphic;
Img : TImage;
EdPath, EdFileName : TEdit;
begin
  openImg.Execute;
  Left := 5;
  Top := 5;
  Count := 0;
  Idx := 0;
for i:=0 to openImg.Files.Count-1 do
  begin
    try
      begin
        Graph := TPngImage.Create;
        Graph.LoadFromFile(openImg.Files[i]);

        EdPath := TEdit.Create(pImgs);
        EdPath.Left := Left + 101;
        EdPath.Visible := False;
        EdPath.Text := ExtractFilePath(openImg.Files[i]);

        EdFileName := TEdit.Create(pImgs);
        EdFileName.Left := Left + 101;
        EdFileName.Visible := False;
        EdFileName.Text := ExtractFileName(openImg.Files[i]);

        Img := TImage.Create(pImgs);
        Img.Parent := pImgs;
        Idx := Idx + 1;
        Img.Name := 'Img_'+IntToStr(Idx);
        Img.Width := 100;
        Img.Height := 100;
        Img.Left := Left;
        Img.Proportional := True;
        Left := Left + 101;
        Img.Top := Top;
        Img.Picture.Assign(Graph);
        Img.BringToFront;
        Count := Count + 1;
        Img.OnClick := getImgInfo(Img, edPath.Text, edFileName.Text); //Error line

        if Count = 2 then
          begin
            Left := 5;
            Top := Top + 101;
            Count := 0;
          end;
      end;
    except on E : Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error: :' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Error:

> [dcc32 Error] uMain.pas(74): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TNotifyEvent' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'

What is wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like this instead:

```
type
  PImageInfo = ^ImageInfo;
  ImageInfo = record
    Path: String;
    FileName: String;
    Img: TImage;
    EdPath: TEdit;
    EdFileName : TEdit;
    // anything else you need...
  end;
```

```
private
  { Private declarations }
  Images: array of ImageInfo;
  procedure ImageClicked(Sender: TObject);
```

```
procedure TfMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, ImgLeft, ImgTop, Count : integer;
  Graph : TGraphic;
  Info: PImageInfo;
begin
  if not openImg.Execute then Exit;

  ImgLeft := 5;
  ImgTop := 5;

  Count := Length(Images);
  try
    SetLength(Images, Count + openImg.Files.Count);

    for I := 0 to openImg.Files.Count-1 do
    begin
      Graph := TPngImage.Create;
      try
        Graph.LoadFromFile(openImg.Files[i]);

        Info := @Images[Count];

        Info.Path := ExtractFilePath(openImg.Files[i]);
        Info.FileName := ExtractFileName(openImg.Files[i]);
        Info.Img := nil;
        Info.EdPath := nil;
        Info.EdFileName := nil;

        try
          Info.EdPath := TEdit.Create(pImgs);
          Info.EdPath.Left := ImgLeft + 101;
          Info.EdPath.Visible := False;
          Info.EdPath.Text := Path;

          Info.EdFileName := TEdit.Create(pImgs);
          Info.EdFileName.Left := ImgLeft + 101;
          Info.EdFileName.Visible := False;
          Info.EdFileName.Text := Images[Count].FileName;

          Info.Img := TImage.Create(pImgs);
          Info.Img.Parent := pImgs;
          Info.Img.Tag := Count;
          Info.Img.Name := 'Img_'+IntToStr(Count);
          Info.Img.SetBounds(ImgLeft, ImgTop, 100, 100);
          Info.Img.Proportional := True;
          Info.Img.OnClick := ImageClicked;
          Info.Img.Picture.Assign(Graph);
          Info.Img.BringToFront;
        except
          Info.EdPath.Free;
          Info.EdFileName.Free;
          Info.Img.Free;
          raise;
        end;
      finally
        Graph.Free;
      end;

      Inc(Count);
      if (Count mod 2) = 0 then
      begin
        ImgLeft := 5;
        Inc(ImgTop, 101);
      end else
        Inc(ImgLeft, 101);
    end;
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      SetLength(Images, Count);
      ShowMessage('Error: :' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TfMain.ImageClicked(Sender: TObject);
var
  Info: PImageInfo;
begin
  Info := @Images[(Sender as TImage).Tag];
  // use Info as needed...
end;
```

Comment: @TLama Personal preference is my only guess.

Comment: @TLama Without first class references in the language, what option is there?

Comment: @TLama: I'm using a pointer because the code is pre-allocating memory before entering the loop, and to avoid the need for using local variables. There are other ways this could be implemented, like using a `TList` of dynamic record instances (but I thought that would be overkill for this example.

Answer (score 5):

The `OnClick` event handler of `TImage` is a `TNotifyEvent`, so you can *only* assign such a procedure to it. This is a *method* (a procedure belonging to an object), and it takes a single parameter, `Sender` of type `TObject`. So this will work:

```
procedure TfMain.ImageClickHandler(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Do something
end;
```

...

```
Img.OnClick := ImageClickHandler;
```

You need some kind of data structure to store your data. Perhaps

```
type
  TImageData = record
    Image: TImage;
    ImageTitle: string;
    ImageFileName: string;
    Photographer: string;
    DateTaken: TDateTime;
  end;
```

and

```
var
  ImageData = array of TImageData;
```

Or, more similar to your code:

```
type
  TImageData = record
    Image: TImage;
    AssociatedEditControl1,
    AssociatedEditControl2: TEdit;
  end;

var
  ImageData = array of TImageData;
```

Then you set the length of `ImageData` to `openImg.Files.Count`, and use `Image` and `AssociatedEditControl1` and `AssociatedEditControl2` instead of the local variables. After all, you want to be able to access these controls easily. You could also set the `Tag` of the `TImage` to the current value of `i`, and then in `ImageClickHandler`, you can check `Self.Tag` to access `ImageData[Self.Tag].AssociatedEditControl1`, say.

(But I still think you should separate the internal data from the GUI better. You also need to fix your memory leak.)

Comment: Andreas, thanks for the reply. That way you did, I know that work. But I need to get the values ​​of EdPath and EdFilename and how do I do it then?

Comment: Save them somewhere. After all, programming is all about *data structures* and algorithms.

Comment: But I need to get the value of each Edit that will be created inside the for and pass to the ImageClickHandler. It's possible?

Comment: There are many ways. But you have to manage your data manually, somehow. Exactly how, I cannot tell, for I don't even know what kind of application you are Writing. But almost certainly, you need to separate data and GUI better...

Comment: What's wrong with A := EdPath.Text and B := EdFileName.Text inside the OnClick event (with A, B local string variables)?

Comment: @GabrielF: `EdPath` and `EdFileName` don't exist in `ImageClickHandler`. And even if they did, they would refer to the *last* image, irrespectively of which image you actually clicked...

Comment: Seems like I really need to start reading the Qs before posting! hehe
Maybe setting tag for TImage object to the same index i, then you can just use openImg.Files[Sender.Tag] inside the event. But that would require keeping openImg in memory.